# How to make or transfer libraries and other things in cs50 codespace to my original and offline VsCode?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, cs50, vscode-remote

I want to code my problem sets and other programms by C language in my VsCode and not the cs50's codespace(in vscode).
I try this and i can code with C language in my vscode but there are some problems like there isn't cs50 library
when i include <cs50.h>, the programm doesn't compile because i haven't cs50 library in my vscode.
What must i do to can code in my vscode offline?
how i transfer all of the things in cs50 codescape to my vscode?

i want to code with C language in my vscode like in my cs50 codespace

new things and tries added:

I found two links for my problem
https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/issues/323

https://cs50.readthedocs.io/cs50.dev/#offline-with-docker

i tried these but i have problem in these too
for the first link i don't know where should i run the second step command.
for the second link i do that works but i don't know where is the folder `foo` and where should i run that last commands.

Comment: https://github.com/cs50/libcs50

Comment: Thank you for this but i have problems in it too.
if you have discord or something please write your id if you can help me in this problem
i can send you my error and issuses.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not here for free personal support. If there are things you tried and you have issues with that then you should edit your question to include those details.